# Convert an UTF-8 varchar to bytea with latin1 encoding in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm porting a proprietary (and old) checksum algorithm from a MySQL procedure to PostgreSQL 8.4.

The whole database is UTF-8, but for this algorithm I need to convert the UTF-8 input to a bytea value with latin1 encoding. In MySQL, variables can be of different encoding and conversion is performed on-the-fly. Is there any function in PostgreSQL to do such an conversion?

The only alternative I see is to write a custom utf8_convert() C function which returns a bytea value and uses internally iconv() to convert the input to latin1. But I want to avoid such C functions.

Answer (score 2):

From [String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
convert_to(text_in_database,'LATIN1')
```

But you have to be sure that the text can be encoded in Latin1 — you'll get an exception otherwise.